# How to configure Nginx for Limonade PHP micro framework?

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

Limonade PHP micro framework works with Nginx. However, I want to get the "pretty url" feature, but I don't know how. For example, I can visit `http://a.com/?/about` without any problems, but I want to make `http://a.com/about` available.

Limonade PHP micro framework provides an [.htacess](https://github.com/sofadesign/limonade/blob/master/examples/urlrewrite/htaccess.conf) file to enable the "pretty url" feature in Apache, but I can't figure out how to do it with Nginx.

I tried :

```
location / { rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?uri=/$1 break; }
```

It seems to work. I can visit `http://a.com/about` instead of `http://a.com/?/about`, but the response from the server is **incredibly slow**, and the framework function `url_for()` doesn't work properly, so there must be something missing.

Can anyone help me find the right way to configure this?

Answer (score 0):

This is coming a little late but in the newest version of the framework this should work.  Put this in your nginx.conf in the server {} section:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

this functionality was added in this [pull request](https://github.com/sofadesign/limonade/pull/26).

See sloonz's comments in the discussion tab for more information.

Comment: https://github.com/sofadesign/limonade/blob/master/examples/urlrewrite/nginx.conf